# When on window.popstate will history.state not equal event.state?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser-history, html5-history

Is there ever a case where `history.state` will not be equal to `event.state` after a [HTML5 `popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event?